# Tools for diagrams like MSDN magazine (Architect's Journal)

Tags: windows, architecture, diagrams

I'm searching for tools for creating diagrams (illustrations) for my articles in my blog about software architecture. Often I read Microsoft Architect's Journal and illustrations at this magazine are very beautiful and comprehensive. Can you help me - what tools are used to create such diagrams ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you interested in applications for a particular operating system (e.g. Windows, Mac OS, *BSD, Linux, …)?

Comment: Sorry, simple, I was thinked if I write magic name "Microsoft" then no need point at OS :) of course Windows is my basic operationg system.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a quick look through the online version, it looks like its pretty much all done it the MSOffice products,Visio, Powerpoint, some excel for charts and data plus some bits are grabs straight from VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) for software diagrams. For general flowcharting there's [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) or OpenOffice Draw. For more general vector illustration there's [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). All of these programs are free software.